# Retrieve form data with function constructor and prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, methods, constructor, prototype

I'm trying to learn function constructors and prototype methods in JavaScript, but I can't seem to quite understand them. I'm trying to retrieve the information from a form, add all the values that are written in the inputs and have a new `<p>` element which combines all of them into a sentence. But I can't make it work...

HTML:

```
<div>
 <form id="questions">
  <input type="text" id="name" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="date"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="hours"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="result"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="Sentence()">
 </form>
 <p id="example"></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Sentence(name, date, hours, result) {
    this.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    this.date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    this.hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
    this.result = document.getElementById('result').value;
};

Sentence.prototype.calcul = function () {
    var x = this.name + " a facut curatenie pe " + this.date + " timp de " + this.hours + " si a fost " + this.result;
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = x;
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="submit" onclick="Sentence()">`

To create an instance off of Function you have to use `new` operator on a function. Also, since the logic for combining all of the properties is in calcul method. You would need something like this:

`<input type="submit" onclick="(new Sentence()).calcul()">`

However, I would suggest you to use the parameters available to `Sentence` constructor to set properties on the sentence instance like so:

```
function Sentence(name, date, hours, result) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.result = result;
};
```

And, your onclick event will look like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="exampleSentence()">
```

Also, since all of this is becoming messy, I would suggest you remove the event handler from the HTML and add it to JavaScript:

```
function exampleSentence() {
    var exampleSentence = new Sentence(document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('date').value, document.getElementById('hours').value, document.getElementById('result').value);
    
    exampleSentence.calcul();
}
```

And, again, since your `calcul` method is responsible for combining the form values into a paragraph, you should refactor the `calcul` method to combine the values and return the resulting sentence but, not be responsible for appending it:

```
Sentence.prototype.calcul = function () {
    var sentence = this.name + " a facut curatenie pe " + this.date + " timp de " + this.hours + " si a fost " + this.result;
    return sentence;
}
```

And, your exampleSentence method will look like:

```
function exampleSentence() {
    var exampleSentence = new Sentence(document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('date').value, document.getElementById('hours').value, document.getElementById('result').value);
    
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = exampleSentence.calcul();
}
```

Result of all of this is:

```js
function exampleSentence(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var exampleSentence = new Sentence(document.getElementById('name').value, document.getElementById('date').value, document.getElementById('hours').value, document.getElementById('result').value);
    
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = exampleSentence.calcul();
}

function Sentence(name, date, hours, result) {
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.hours = hours;
    this.result = result;
};

Sentence.prototype.calcul = function () {
    var sentence = this.name + " a facut curatenie pe " + this.date + " timp de " + this.hours + " si a fost " + this.result;
    return sentence;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <form id="questions">
  <input type="text" id="name" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="date"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="hours"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="result"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="exampleSentence(event)">
 </form>
 <p id="example"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Wouldn't it be a bad practice to add that much javascript data in the HTML file? As from what I was reading online, I should try to write as little JavaScript in the HTML document as possible, and to keep them separate.

Comment: @Ciprian I was writing the answer in a progressive manner. Please check out the edits as that's exactly what I suggest!

Comment: I read your respone now, thanks for the detailed explanation, works great! It seems that I need to read about preventDefault(), as I didn't quite understand what is doing. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Ciprian There are default behaviors attached to HTML elements and the default behavior of a `button` element in `form` element if not explicitly specified as `type="button"` is to submit the form to a given URL and since you didn't specify `action` attribute on your `form`, the default behavior is to submit back to itself. All of which translates to a page refresh, just in this case. We don't want that. So, we tell browser explicitly that we don't want default behaviors to execute with `preventDefault()`. Good luck! Keep learning.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for spreading the knowledge, and for the encouragement! Good luck to you too!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```js
function Sentence() {
    this.name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    this.date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    this.hours = document.getElementById('hours').value;
    this.result = document.getElementById('result').value;
};

Sentence.prototype.calcul = function () {
    var x = this.name + " a facut curatenie pe " + this.date + " timp de " + this.hours + " si a fost " + this.result;
    document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = x;
    return x;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <p id="example"></p>
 <form id="questions">
  <input type="text" id="name" ><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="date"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="hours"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="result"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="new Sentence().calcul()">
 </form>
</div>
```